# Not getting proper response of error body using retrofit

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

in login,Actually my success response is displayed properly on toast.but when typed wrong details,the error body response is not getting displayed properly

here is my response-->

```
{
"status": 401,
"data": false,
"message": "User login unsuccessful.",
"user_msg": "Email or password is wrong. try again"
}
```

my following code:

```
override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<LoginResponse>,
                    response: Response<LoginResponse>
                ) {
                    var res = response

                    Log.d("response check ", "" + response.body()?.status.toString())
                    if (res.body()?.status==200) {

                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
                            .saveUser(response.body()?.data!!)

                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java)
                        intent.flags =
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            res.body()?.message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                        Log.d("kjsfgxhufb",response.body()?.status.toString())
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()


                    }

            else
                    {
                        try {
                            val jObjError =
                                JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                            Toast.makeText(
                                applicationContext,
                                jObjError.getJSONObject("user_msg").getString("message"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                           Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                    }
```

my output is on toast:

```
Value Email or password is wrong. try again at user_msg of type java.lang.String cannot be 
converted to JSONObject
```

actually i dont want toast error msg like this..i want simple message like "email or password is wrong. try again"

help me thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are trying to getJSONObject from `"user_msg"` which is not possible because `"user_msg"` **is not a JSONObject, it is a String**.

A JSONObject would looks like:

```
"user_msg": {
   "message": "Your error"
}
```

But that is not the case, you are getting two different String values.

```
"user_msg": "message",
"message" : "another message"
```

What you should do is `jObjError.getString("user_msg")` to get the value from `"user_msg"`, and another `jObjError.getString("message")` to get the value from `"message"`.

Comment: hey can you help here -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63114801/how-should-i-fetch-images-under-the-array-using-retrofit?noredirect=1#comment111610152_63114801