# How should I fetch images under an array using retrofit

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I have images under array...here is my json:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "product_category_id": 1,
        "name": "Centre Coffee Table",
        "producer": "Luna",
        "description": "Mild Steel Base In Poder Coated White Finish.8 mm Tempered Glass Table Top.Bottom Shelf In Paimted Brown Glass.",
        "cost": 5000,
        "rating": 3,
        "view_count": 21243,
        "created": "2015-09-07T09:24:05+0000",
        "modified": "2020-07-27T10:52:42+0000",
        "product_images": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "product_id": 1,
                "image": "http://staging.php-dev.in:8844/trainingapp/uploads/prod_img/thumb/medium/9dc6234da018916e545011fa1.jpeg",
                "created": "2015-09-07T09:40:00+0000",
                "modified": "2015-09-07T09:40:00+0000"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "product_id": 1,
                "image": "http://staging.php-dev.in:8844/trainingapp/uploads/prod_img/thumb/medium/1bfdac02ced672dd1e8e8976c.jpeg",
                "created": "2015-09-07T09:44:11+0000",
                "modified": "2015-09-07T09:44:11+0000"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### From the above json you'll see there are two images under `product_images` array

**I will tell you images under `product_images` are not fixed ...it could be differnt ids..can be contain 3 or 2 or 1 or 4**

Here is my second json response where id 3 ids with 3 images are retrive under array-->

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "id": 5,
        "product_category_id": 2,
        "name": "HP Fabric Office Chair",
        "producer": "HP",
        "description": "Serene Staff Chair\r\nFive Star Nylon Base with Nylon Castor\r\nFree Delivery",
        "cost": 2222,
        "rating": 3,
        "view_count": 2335,
        "created": "2015-09-07T09:48:51+0000",
        "modified": "2020-07-27T11:50:51+0000",
        "product_images": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "product_id": 5,
                "image": "http://staging.php-dev.in:8844/trainingapp/uploads/prod_img/thumb/medium/fddd92b395be88ce117936b9f.jpeg",
                "created": "2015-09-07T09:49:33+0000",
                "modified": "2015-09-07T09:49:33+0000"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "product_id": 5,
                "image": "http://staging.php-dev.in:8844/trainingapp/uploads/prod_img/thumb/medium/78b1d4e168280fe5f9cfdff60.jpeg",
                "created": "2015-09-07T09:49:51+0000",
                "modified": "2015-09-07T09:49:51+0000"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "product_id": 5,
                "image": "http://staging.php-dev.in:8844/trainingapp/uploads/prod_img/thumb/medium/b6480396b91bb9e99e40e4ba7.jpeg",
                "created": "2015-09-07T09:50:10+0000",
                "modified": "2015-09-07T09:50:10+0000"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my retrofit activity:

```
RetrofitClient.instancetable.fetchUserdetail(id)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<Product_base_response> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Product_base_response>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("res", "" + t)

            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<Product_base_response>,
                response: Response<Product_base_response>
            ) {
                var res = response

             val ret: Product_Data_response? =res.body()?.data
                val retro: List<Product_images_response> = res.body()?.data?.product_images!!

                Log.e("checkdata",ret?.name.toString())
                val ygd=ret?.name.toString()
                text.setText(ygd)
                text2.setText(ret?.producer.toString())
           //need help in here -->>>> 
               Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(res?.body()!!.data.product_images.get(0).image).into(imagemain);
                for ( i in res?.body()!!.data.product_images.indices.toString()){//crashes if contain image under get(1)
                     Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(res?.body()!!.data.product_images.get(1).image).into(imagemain1);


                }
               Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(res?.body()!!.data.product_images.get(2).image).into(imagemain2);
               Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(res?.body()!!.data.product_images.get(3).image).into(imagemain3);

            }
        })
}
```

**From above retrofit response code it got crashes when it  not deteected get(1) in image array**

**NOTE: I have to load those images in 4 imageviews and also note images are not fixed as you can see json 1 and json 2**.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Why are you doing a loop but always getting `1`?

Comment: see in `product_image` array...images with ids are not fixed....it can contain one object(one image) or it can go upto total four object(four images)  ....i was trying to get it under loop like depending upon size of objects under `product_image` array....do you have in mind how should handle @cutiko

Comment: If you are using a loop to traverse the array but hardcoding the position `1` what is the point of the loop? `load(res?.body()!!.data.product_images.get(1).image)` -> `product_images.get(i).image` ? Where `i` is the index on the loop

Comment: if i do `product_images.get(i).image` it shows image in imagemain1 (get(1))...but for second image it crashes for to load in imagemain2(that is get(2))

Comment: it also fails /crashes if it json contain only image of get(0) of imagemain  not get(1) imagemain1 @cutiko

Comment: what is the stacktrace?

Comment: @Wini what is crash stacktrace log? Also please, post `Product_base_response` class.

Comment: @Wini hellooo, could you please help me out at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498385/how-to-pass-parameters-in-webview 
at here, if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

First off create model classes from your response, for that copy your response and add your response here http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/  , here it will create all pojo classes from your response.

Now...
change you api call method

```
Call<Product_base_response>
```

to

```
Call<JsonObject>
```

Now just print response in onResponse method like

```
Log.d("===","onResponse :: "+response.body());
```

if you got your response here,

```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
Your_Main_Model mainModel = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), Your_Main_Model.class);
```

Now, to get images you need to go through main model like

```
Main_model.data_object_model.product_images_model_list.get(0).getImage();
```

Hope this works, if you didn't get it or this not work let me know